# For Windows there is Win32 API, what about for Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

For Windows there is Win32 API, what about for Mac?  On Wikipedia

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29)

it is said that Cocoa is "one of" the API...  what about the full story?

Comment: Have you gone to the Apple Developer site?  http://developer.apple.com/  Seems to have the documentation you're looking for.  What's missing?  What more do you need to know?  Can you provide a specific link or quote that confuses you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At what level?  The low level API is largely but not entirely FreeBSD, and below that there is still a Mach API (some things still use Mach ports for IPC, I believe; at least, launchd supports them).  At the upper level are two APIs:  Cocoa and Carbon.  Cocoa is the native API; Carbon is intended for programs ported from older MacOS.  (Which includes parts of OSX itself; for a long time Finder was a Carbon app.)

The Windows situation isn't all that different, actually; there was for a long time a Win16 emulation API present in 32-bit Windows, and in the early days of Windows NT it had both POSIX and 16-bit OS/2 APIs.

Comment: The Windows situation *still* isn't all that different, with .NET being promoted as the way to go for new code, and Win32 still supported for older apps.

Answer (score 2):

That pretty much *is* the full story. Mac OS X does support other APIs, but they're either deprecated (Carbon), or intended primarily to support "foreign" software (Java, X11, POSIX). The native API is Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X is [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X) underneath.  That's the "other" API.