# Speed up concatenation of excel files with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, performance, pandas, concatenation

I'm trying to merge multiple excel files with pandas using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from os.path import basename


df = []
for f in ['test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx']:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    data.index = [basename(f)] * len(data)
    df.append(data)

df = pd.concat(df)

df.to_excel("merged_data2.xlsx")
```

Which works fine on the test files but when trying it on 3 other excel files of size over 100mb each the process becomes too slow to be useful. I saw this other post on the subject: [Why does concatenation of DataFrames get exponentially slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower)

And I believe I have correctly followed the advice of using a list before concatenating but without success. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your pandas code; a 300mb excel file might just be a lot for Pandas to handle! Here are some approaches I'd take:

### Tactic 1. Investigate

If I were you, my next step in debugging this would be to throw some `print(datetime.now())` statements into the loop, to see whether it's the reading, the concatenating, or the `.to_excel` that's taking time. That way you may be able to narrow down the problem. Also take a look at your memory usage using appropriate tools for whatever OS you're in.

### Tactic 2. Try a different tool

Pandas is optimized for scientific computing and it probably spends quite a bit of time organizing the data for querying and such. ETL isn't it's primary purpose. If you only need to concatenate a few sheets, (as much as it pains me to suggest doing something manually!) manual work in Excel itself will likely be the quickest way to go - highly-paid engineers at Microsoft have been tasked with optimizing that. If you need a programmatic approach, it could be worth trying out [petl](http://petl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html#excel-xlsx-files-openpyxl) or one of the tools discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142420/can-pandas-read-and-modify-a-single-excel-file-worksheet-tab-without-modifying?rq=1) that may take a simpler/more efficient approach than pandas.

Some example `petl` code that might do the trick:

```
import petl
petl.cat(*
    petl.io.fromxlsx(file)
    for file in ['your.xlsx', 'excel.xlsx', 'files.xlsx']
).progress().toxlsx()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was keeping an eye on the memory usage, which fluctuated between a few hundred mb to over 4gb for long stretches. Overall the process did finish but took over an hour on a 8 core amd CPU with 8gb of RAM. Ill try your other suggestions out and investigate further. Thanks!