# Excel: modify sheet exists without alter other sheet with pivot table using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My problem main is when modify one sheet and save the book, all sheet save as text include sheet with pivot table.

This is my code:

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('book1.xlsx')
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('my_data')
sheet['A2'] = 'hello world'
xfile.save('book2.xlsx') #all sheets of book save as text
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142420/can-pandas-read-and-modify-a-single-excel-file-worksheet-tab-without-modifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue today.  I updated my openpyxl to be version 2.5 and it worked fine.  Have you tried updating and still getting the issue?

Comment: Thanks Eric! I fixed my problem only upgrading the library openpyxl to version 2.5.

I am working with Anaconda in Windows, then, for library update execute this command in consola:

conda install -c conda-forge openpyxl